# How to analysis one row into several rows according to num of map.keys

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset

I am trying to read a dataset and process it; dataset row type is (string,string,string,Map[String,String]), the num of Map.keys is from 1 to 3,so one row will become 1-3 rows like(string,string,string,k,v). 
I actually realize it using code as follows:

```
var arr  = new ArrayBuffer[Array[String]]()
myDataset.collect.foreach{
f:(String,String,String,Map[String,String]) =>
    val ma = f._4
    for((k,v)<-ma) {
        arr += Array(f._1,f._2,f._3,k,v)
    }
}
```

Orgdata like this(one row in mydataset:hundreds of millions ):

```
val a = ("111","222","333",Map("k1"->"v1","k2"->"v2"))
```

expected output:

```
("111","222","333","k1","v1")
("111","222","333","k2","v2")
```

But big data cause OOM problem,so is there other ways to accomplish this ? or how to optimize my code to avoid  OOM?

Comment: It goes without saying that you have to avoid `collect` if you have a lot of data. Also, can you please add your sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `explode` the map column and then select the exploded columns :

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Array(
    ("111","222","333",Map("k1"->"v1","k2"->"v2"))
)).toDF("a", "b", "c", "d")

df.select($"*", explode($"d") )
  .select("a", "b", "c" ,"key", "value")
  .as[(String, String, String, String, String)]
  .first
// (String, String, String, String, String) = (111,222,333,k1,v1)
```